# Adding widgets and arranging them to the corner of the screen on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, layout, qt5

I tried to arrange some widgets which includes two labels and one image on the top right of the screen. I am using a HBoxlayout. When I tried to add the widgets to the screen in HBoxlayout, all the widgets are not getting arranged at the position I want them to placed at. So how can I arrange these to the top of the screen.Here is the code which I tried

```
#include "screen.h"
#include "ui_screen.h"
#include<QGridLayout>
#include<QLabel>
#include<QBitmap>

screen::screen(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::screen)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGridLayout *g=new QGridLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *h=new QHBoxLayout();
    QLabel *l=new QLabel();
    QLabel *l2=new QLabel();
    QLabel *l3=new QLabel();
    QPixmap p(":/img/img/user.jpg");
    l->setPixmap(p);
    l->setMask(p.mask());
    l->show();
    l->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : blue; }");
    l2->setText("User");
    l3->setText("Value");
    h->addWidget(l,0,Qt::AlignRight);
    h->addWidget(l2,0,Qt::AlignRight);
    h->addWidget(l3,0,Qt::AlignRight);
    g->addLayout(h,0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignTop);
    this->setLayout(g);
    this->showFullScreen();
}

screen::~screen()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The layout which I tried to make [Sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOl4d.png)

[image]

right now I haven't added the left sided labels yet in my code. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why do you have `ui->setupUi(this);`? This is used when you have UI created in Qt Designer (by mouse). If you have some layout setup in Designer than your widget already have a layout and layout can't be replaced (Qt logs respective warring about that).

Comment: Actually I forgot to remove this. But I am not getting at the final point that how to make this structure.

Comment: looks like your items are getting stretched . Use `addStretch` so the free space is stretched instead your labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with the layouts like this:

```
#include "screen.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QFrame>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *widget = new QWidget(this);
    auto *frmLogin = new QFrame(this);
    auto *layoutMain = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    auto *layoutTitle = new QHBoxLayout();
    auto *layoutLogin = new QHBoxLayout(frmLogin);
    auto *layoutInfo = new QVBoxLayout();
    auto *labTitle = new QLabel(tr("Some other stuff you want in the title"), this);
    auto *labBody = new QLabel(tr("Some other stuff you want in the body"), this);
    auto *labAvatar = new QLabel(this);
    auto *labUser = new QLabel(tr("User"), this);
    auto *labValue = new QLabel(tr("Value"), this);
    QPixmap p(":/pix/images/avatars/user.png");

    labTitle->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    labTitle->setStyleSheet(".QLabel { background-color: white; }");

    labBody->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    labAvatar->setPixmap(p);
    labAvatar->setMask(p.mask());

    layoutInfo->addWidget(labUser);
    layoutInfo->addWidget(labValue);

    layoutLogin->addWidget(labAvatar);
    layoutLogin->addLayout(layoutInfo);

    frmLogin->setStyleSheet(".QFrame { background-color : orange; }");
    frmLogin->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

    layoutTitle->addWidget(labTitle);
    layoutTitle->addWidget(frmLogin);

    layoutMain->addLayout(layoutTitle);
    layoutMain->addWidget(labBody);
    layoutMain->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layoutMain->setSpacing(0);

    setCentralWidget(widget);
    showFullScreen();
}
```

The code above results in the following layout:

[image]